# Java TrayIcon.displayMessage() and line-breaks

Tags: java, trayicon, line-breaks

I'm writing a Java app with a SystemTray icon, and I'd like to put line-breaks into the TrayIcon's "display message", but the normal html trick doesn't seem to work (like it does inside JLabels).

In the example below, the trayIcon variable below is of type "java.awt.TrayIcon".

`trayIcon.displayMessage("Title", "<p>Blah</p> \r\n Blah <br> blah ... blah", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);`

Java ignores the \r\n, but displays the html tags.

Any ideas?

If not, I'll use a JFrame or something.

**UPDATE:** it seems to be a platform-specific issue, and I should have specified my OS in the question: I need this to work on Windows and Linux.

Nishan showed that a \n works on Windows, and I confirmed with a Vista box I now have next to me.
It *looks* like I'll need to make something custom with a JFrame or a messagebox

Cheers guys

Comment: try this: `"<HtMl><p>Blah</p> \r\n Blah <br> blah ... blah"`

Comment: This issue is not yet resolved. Visit this link - http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6440297

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending \n worked for me :

```
"<HtMl><p>Blah</p> \n Blah <br> blah ... blah"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Oracle JDK 6u24 on Ubuntu). Simply shows the tags as plain text.

Comment: I'm also using Ubuntu. Nishan, what OS are you running?

Comment: I am on a windows box, jdk 6u06

Comment: I can confirm that it works on Windows Vista. +1 for Windows, eh :(

Comment: accepting this answer because I believe it's outside Java's control. It's OS-specific.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6440297), it is not possible to show new lines in tray icon messages in Linux.

Just now got a tricky idea which worked for me. Observed number of characters getting displayed per line in the message. For me it is showing 56 characters per line.

So, if a line has got less than 56 characters, fill the gap with spaces to make it 56 characters.

Knew this is not a proper way but could not find other alternatives. Now my output is as expected.

```
private java.lang.String messageToShow = null;
private int lineLength = 56;
/*This approach is showing ellipses (...) at the end of the last line*/
public void addMessageToShow(java.lang.String messageToShow) {
        if (this.messageToShow == null){
            this.messageToShow = messageToShow;
        }else{
            this.messageToShow += "\n" + messageToShow;//Working perfectly in windows.
        }
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux")){
            /*
             Fill with blank spaces to get the next message in next line.
             Checking with mod operator to handle the line which wraps 
             into multiple lines
            */
            while (this.messageToShow.length() % lineLength > 0){
                this.messageToShow += " ";
            }
        }
    }
```

So, i tried another approach

```
/*This approach is not showing ellipses (...) at the end of the last line*/
public void addMessageToShow(java.lang.String messageToShow) {
    if (this.messageToShow == null){
        this.messageToShow = messageToShow;
    }else{
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux")){
            /*
             Fill with blank spaces to get the next message in next line.
             Checking with mod operator to handle the line which wraps 
             into multiple lines
            */
            while (this.messageToShow.length() % lineLength > 0){
                this.messageToShow += " ";
            }
        }else{
            this.messageToShow += "\n";// Works properly with windows
        }
        this.messageToShow += messageToShow;
    }
}
```

And finally

```
trayIcon.displayMessage("My Title", this.messageToShow, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
```

Comment: Thx for the workaround. I now use it, too. How did you determine the line length of 56 characters? Try and error? Anyway I would recommend not to hardcode the number 56 or at least give it a name in a dedicated variable with a comment and a reason why you did it, to avoid magic numbers.

Comment: I did trail and error method only to derive at that number 56. Updated my code upon your suggestion to avoid "magic numbers" usage.